# Powershell generic admin id checker

Tags: powershell, active-directory, mmc

Can someone help me with powershell script to check a genric admin id has logon access on which all machines.

I just need to give input a generic admin id(eg admin\abcd) and it returns all the workstations/servers/machines on which it has access.

This feature we can check from MMC snap-in and searching that id and going to properties-->log on. This gives all the machines.

But I am looking for some alternative to check directly from my powershell console and later I can add the script to my tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Active Directory module:

Get-ADUser 'userName' -Properties logonworkstations

Comment: Thanks for quick response Smith but will it work for generic id's that is shared or is not tied to a specific user

Comment: If it's an Active Directory logon, this will work. Based on your description this sounds like a generic AD account that is granted access to logon to various servers/workstations.

Answer (score 0):

But the problem is it throws an error evertime and says can not find an object with identity ADMIN/comprise under dc=prod, DC=travp, DC=net

This is because this genric id was created in admin domain....how to get these results..

Using mmc snap in, i need to search in entire directory then I get this instead of prod.travp.net

Comment: In that case, use the -Server parameter to Get-ADUser and specify a domain controller in the ADMIN domain.